# Не вставляются греческие символы в формулу, выдаёт ошибку или пишется иной символ

Tags: latex

Использую дистрибутив MIKTeX на TeXstudio. Не вводится символ омеги, хотя правила перехода в математический режим соблюдены ($ \omega $). Вместо символа вылезает восклицательный знак.
Причем, например, число "пи" при вводе $ \pi $ ошибку не выдаёт, но вместо самого числа "пи" почему-то вылазит "бета".
Помогите, пожалуйста. Сил уже нет, который день пытаюсь разобраться в этой ситуации...
Если что, используются такие пакеты:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{misccorr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
```

Одна из формул:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$$G_\textsc{x}(z)=\sum\limits_{ \omega \in \Omega }Pr(\omega)z^{\textsc{x}( \omega )} = E(z^\textsc{x})\text{.}\eqno(8\text{.}26)$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к тексту вопроса (нажав [edit]) лог компиляции файла с вот таким, например, содержимым: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}$\alpha\beta\gamma\pi\omega$\end{document}` (больше в файле ничего быть не должно).

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущего оратора - нужен log. Ваш пример+пакеты на нормально (без проблем) установленной системе компилируется и работает правильно. Проблемы можно искать в таких направлениях: 1) какую кодировку файла Вы используете? - если ничего не указывать, последние версии миктеха ждут utf-8, если правильно помню;  2) может быть установлен не полный дистрибутив миктеха и почему-то не работает установка пакетов по запросу; 3) может быть повреждена система (по какой-то причине пропали файлы некоторых шрифтов - например, из-за повреждения жесткого диска).

Comment: Использовала кодировку utf-8, ноутбук новый, устанавливала миктех и всё остальное под надзором знающего человека (у которого сейчас, к слову, не могу помощи попросить). Большое спасибо за ответ!
В итоге я все-таки решила проблему - использовала пакет textgreek и писала \textomega. 
Понимаю, что разобраться в проблеме всё равно стоит. Возможно, всё-таки попробую переустановить миктех.

Comment: Было бы круто добавить в вопрос публичную ссылку на новый простой проект, в котором возникает ошибка. Например, на этот онлайн-редактор tex:
https://www.overleaf.com/
Тогда мы (читатели) сразу смогли бы скомпилировать и сказать причину ошибки.

Comment: Хотя, к сожалению, overleaf не позволяет просматривать проекты незарегистрированным пользователям, так что моя идея не очень хороша. Но ваш код из вопроса в нем скомпилировался (но было  предупреждение компилятора, пока я не скопировал usepackage из вопроса)

Comment: @MikhailIonkin, да вроде аналоги overleaf есть. например: latexbase, tutorialspoint, cocalc. не тестировал: всё из результатов поиска «latex online editor».

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в latexbase регистрация не обязательна, код кимпилируется. Но в нем и, скажем, в tutorialspoint нет нормальной компиляции с подгрузкой ссылок в формулах, нет иерархии файлов. Да и с русскими буквами там проблемы.